# Custom UITableViewCell multiple sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, sectionheader

As i am newbie to this development, i am requesting  you to give a fast reply for my below requirement.

My iPhone application is: Requesting data from web page(with php) and showing it in my table. This table contains  multiple lines of information: imageView, 3 rows(user name, category, no.of views) in one column, and user email id in next column..

To get this type of tableView, i used custom UITableViewCell reference,NSURLConnection methods, loaded content(multiple records) in the table at-a-time and everything works fine.

But, i would like to change in this design as:

(i) I want to show my tableView with multiple sections..based on category-wise(which is dynamic-not fixed no.of values).

(ii) I want to make category name as section title..

I am hitting my head to get this type of functionality in my app from one week. I referred apple documentation & googled web.but, i was unable to find any resource to match my requirement..

Is this possible?.If you any one of you tried this, kindly suggest me how to proceed further..

Waiting for your valuable response..

Ramya.

Comment: What specific problem are you having with adding sections? Are you correctly responding to the various UITableViewDelegate methods?

Answer (score 1):

(i) `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`

(ii) `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Comment: Can any one you tell me how to upload/add an image while putting a question in stack overflow?. Then i can explain you the requirement a-bit more clear.